# Rails, named route with regexp doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to, named-routing

I have following problem and I can't understand why it's doesn't work:

I have routes:

```
get "/:id" => 'landings#show_direct',  as: :direct_landing,  id: /ticket-from-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/
get "/:id" => 'landings#show_reverse', as: :reverse_landing, id: /ticket-to-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/
```

And it's work fine

```
localhost:3000/ticket-form-moscow
localhost:3000/ticket-to-moscow
```

rake routes | grep landing

```
direct_landing  GET /:id(.:format) landings#show_direct {:id=>/ticket-from-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/}
reverse_landing GET /:id(.:format) landings#show_reverse {:id=>/ticket-to-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/}
```

But when I try to build link

```
= link_to @landing.title_to, reverse_landing_url('ticket-to-moscow')
```

I have error message

```
No route matches {:action=>"show_reverse", :controller=>"landings", :id=>"ticket-to-moscow", :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Try `reverse_landing_url(:id => 'ticket-to-moscow')`

Comment: `localhost:3000/ticket-form-moscow` actually shouldn't work, typo here in question? I think it is connected with Rails default resource behaviour. May be it considers path parametr as :id if path specifies contoller? Try `/landing/:id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all!

it was my mistake

You should to use

```
get "/:id", to: 'landings#show_direct',  as: :direct_landing,  id: /ticket-from-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/
```

instead

```
get "/:id" => 'landings#show_direct',  as: :direct_landing,  id: /ticket-from-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/
```

Now following helper works fine

```
direct_landing_url(:id => 'ticket-to-moscow')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably try a different strategy.

```
get 'tickets/to/:id' => 'landings#show_direct', as: 'tickets_to'
get 'tickets/from/:id' => 'landings#show_reverse', as: 'tickets_from'
```

Then:

```
link_to "Tickets to Moscow!", tickets_to_url('Moscow')
link_to "Tickets from Moscow!", tickets_from_url('Moscow')
```